My nav bar is not showing over the gif file
The navigation bar I have for the top of the site is not showng when I view the top of the site, it only shows when start to scroll down, and when I do scroll down images keeps hovering over it. How can I fix this? any help would be greatly appricated!
here is the link to the github: https://github.com/laurenseel/Lauren-Phoebe


body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #6e568d;
  /* overflow-x: hidden; */
  scrollbar-gutter: stable;
  font-family: 'agrandir';
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'agrandir';
  src: url(Agrandir.OTF) format("opentype");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

p {
  font-family: 'agrandir';
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #a18eff;
  text-align: center;
  /* text is centered*/
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  /* there is no space at the top*/
  width: 100%;
  /* makes it maxed out to the sides */
  font-weight: bold;
}

.navbar a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000000;
  /* text color in the bar */
  padding: 20px 130px;
  /* determines the padding for the top and down, and the left and right. */
  text-decoration: none;
  /* makes sure there is no underline on the text */
}

.navbar a:hover {
  /* when you hover over text the color changes */
  background-color: #2b00ff;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.brandname {
  padding-top: -100px;
  padding-left: 1px;
  margin-top: -1100px;
  margin-bottom: -300px;
  text-align: center;
}

.logo {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.underlogosocials {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: -50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 730px;
}

.color1block {
  /* block where the music is playing */
  background-color: #6e568d;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 150px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  /* scrolling */
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-bottom: -160px;
  /* fix that small space that hides in the side scroll */
  display: flex;
}

.color1block p {
  /* margin-top: 10px; */
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'agrandir';
}


/*.audio-container { no need for an audio player class 
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
} */

.popout img {
  /* Set maximum width for images */
  /* Maintain aspect ratio */
  /* Add margin around each image */
  transition: transform 0.3s ease, box-shadow 0.3s ease;
  /* Add smooth transition */
}

.popout img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  /* Scale up the image */
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  /* Add a shadow */
}

.aboutcontainer {
  background-image: url(images/background2.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: -16px;
  margin-top: 160px;
  align-items: center;
}


/* no longer needed, we do not use the bigger picture 
.image-container { 
  overflow-x: auto; Enable horizontal scrolling 
  white-space: nowrap; Prevent line breaks 
  background: #2b00ff; 
  margin-right: 10px; 
 } 
 */


/* no longer needed, we do not use the bigger picture 
.image-container img {
  display: inline-block;  Display images horizontally 
}
*/

.aboutimage {
  width: 200px;
  /* Set maximum width for the image */
  height: 800px;
  /* Maintain aspect ratio */
  margin-right: 20px;
  /* Add margin to create space between image and text */
}

.abouttext {
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* Allow text to grow to fill remaining space */
}


/* no longer needed
.merchcontainer{
  width: 100%;
  height: 880px;
}
*/

.aboutimages123 {
  margin: 30px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 350px;
}


/* not wanted 
.aboutcontainer p {
  background-color: rgb(171, 164, 255);
  display: inline-block;
} 
*/

.contactcontainer {
  background-color: #402e58;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.contactcontainer p {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.social-media-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.social-link {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #402e58;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.social-logo {
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-right: -130px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.tooltip-container {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tooltip-text {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 550px;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip-container:hover .tooltip-text {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/logo.png">
  <title>Lauren Pheobe Music</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="home"> </p>
  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="#home">HOME</a>
    <a href="#listennow">CATALOG</a>
    <a href="#about">ABOUT</a>
    <a href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
  </div>
  <img src="images/Video Background (1).gif" style="width: 100%;">
  <div class="brandname"><img src="images/brandname.png" alt="Lauren Pheobe name"></div>
  <div class="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Lauren Pheobe logo" height="450px" width="450px"></div>
  <div class="underlogosocials">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/facebook2.png" style="height: 50px;" width="80px"></a>
    </a>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/laurenphebs" target="_blank"><img src="images/twitter2.png" style="height: 50px;" width="80px"></a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/laurenphoebemusic/" target="_blank"><img src="images/instagram2.png" style="height: 50px;" width="80px"></a>
    <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@laurenphoebemusic?lang=en" target="_blank"><img src="images/tiktok2.png" style="height: 50px;" width="80px"></a>
  </div>
  <p id="listennow"> </p>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p style="text-align:center; font-size: 40px"><b> Click Image to Stream Full Song! </b></p>
  <div class="color1block popout">
    <div>
      <a href="https://distrokid.com/hyperfollow/laurenphoebe/are-you-ready-feat-the-fragile-corpse" target="_blank"><img style="padding: 1px 50px 1px 50px;" src="images/Are You Ready.png" alt="Are You Ready" height="300px" width="300px"></a>
      <p>Are You Ready
        <span class="tooltip-container">
            
            <span class="tooltip-text">
                Title: Are You Ready <br>
                Artist: Lauren Phoebe (Feat. The Fragile Corpse)<br>
                Genre: Alt Rock<br>
                Mood: Sad / Contemplative<br>
                Composer/Lyricist/Producer: Lauren M Seel - Matthew W Manninen<br>
                ISRC: QZHNC2431553<br>
                BMI: Artist 1 (50%) Artist 2 (50%) <br>
                BPM: 78<br>
                Year: 2024<br>
            </span>
        </span>
      </p>
      </span>
      </span>
      </p>
      <audio controls style="margin: 0 auto; display: block;">
        <source src="MP3/Are You Ready.wav" type="audio/ogg" > 
      </audio>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="https://distrokid.com/hyperfollow/laurenphoebe/by-morning" target="_blank"><img style="padding: 1px 50px 1px 50px;" src="images/By_Morning.png" alt="By Morning" height="300px" width="300px"></a>
      <p>By Morning
        <span class="tooltip-container">
                
                <span class="tooltip-text">
                    Title: By Morning<br>
                    Artist: Lauren Phoebe (Feat. The Fragile Corpse)<br>
                    Genre: Alt Rock<br>
                    Mood: Somber / Contemplative<br>
                    Composer/Lyricist/Producer: Lauren M Seel - Matthew W Manninen<br>
                    ISRC: QZK6P2305069<br>
                    BMI: Artist 1 (50%) Artist 2 (50%) <br>
                    BPM: 130<br>
                    Year: 2023<br>
                </span>
        </span>
      </p>
      <audio controls style="margin: 0 auto; display: block;">
            <source src="MP3/By Morning.mp3" type="audio/ogg">
        </audio>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="https://distrokid.com/hyperfollow/laurenphoebe/shaken-feat-the-fragile-corpse" target="_blank"><img style="padding: 1px 50px 1px 50px;" src="images/Shaken.png" alt="Shaken" height="300px" width="300px"></a>
      <p>Shaken
        <span class="tooltip-container">
                
                <span class="tooltip-text">
                    Title: Shaken<br>
                    Artist: Lauren Phoebe (Feat. The Fragile Corpse)<br>
                    Genre: Alt Rock / Pop<br>
                    Mood: Encouragement / Empowerment<br>
                    Composer/Lyricist/Producer: Lauren M Seel - Matthew W Manninen<br>
                    ISRC: QZHN32457827<br>
                    BMI: Artist 1 (50%) Artist 2 (50%) <br>
                    BPM: 162<br>
                    Year: 2024<br>

                </span>
        </span>
      </p>
      <audio controls style="margin: 0 auto; display: block;">
            <source src="MP3/Shaken.mp3" type="audio/ogg">
        </audio>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="https://distrokid.com/hyperfollow/laurenphoebe/deep-deep-down" target="_blank"><img style="padding: 1px 50px 1px 50px;" src="images/Deep_down.png" alt="Deep down" height="300px" width="300px"></a>
      <p>Deep down
        <span class="tooltip-container">
                
            <span class="tooltip-text">
                Title: Deep Deep Down<br>
                Artist: Lauren Phoebe (Feat. The Fragile Corpse)<br>
                Genre: Alt Rock /  Pop<br>
                Mood: Focused / Angst<br>
                Composer/Lyricist/Producer: Lauren M Seel - Matthew W Manninen<br>
                ISRC: QZES72493058<br>
                BMI: Artist 1 (50%) Artist 2 (50%) <br>
                BPM: 175<br>
                Year: 2024<br>

            </span>
        </span>
      </p>
      <audio controls style="margin: 0 auto; display: block; ">
            <source src="MP3/Deep Deep Down.mp3" type="audio/ogg">
        </audio>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="https://distrokid.com/hyperfollow/laurenphoebe/shaken-feat-the-fragile-corpse" target="_blank"><img style="padding: 1px 50px 1px 50px;" src="images/Tell Me Your Secrets.png" alt="Tell Me Your Secrets" height="300px" width="300px"></a>
      <p>Tell Me Your Secrets
        <span class="tooltip-container">
                
                <span class="tooltip-text">
                    Title: Tell Me Your Secrets<br>
                    Artist: Lauren Phoebe (Feat. The Fragile Corpse)<br>
                    Genre: Alt Rock / Pop / Indie<br>
                    Moody: Happy / Empowerment<br>
                    Composer/Lyricist/Producer: Lauren M Seel - Matthew W Manninen<br>
                    ISRC: QZK6P2471424<br>
                    BMI: Artist 1 (50%) Artist 2 (50%) <br>
                    BPM: 125<br>
                    Year: 2024<br>
                </span>
        </span>
      </p>

      <audio controls style="margin: 0 auto; display: block; ">
          <source src="MP3/Tell Me All Your Secrets.mp3" type="audio/ogg">
         </audio>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <p id="about"> </p>
  <div class="aboutcontainer">
    <div class="abouttext">
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <img class="aboutimage" style="float: left;" height="1px" src="images/vine.png">
      <img class="aboutimages123 " src="images/about img 1.jpg" style="float: right;">
      <p style="font-size:250%;"> <b>Lauren Phoebe is a Midwest Pop & Alt rock artist. </b> </p>
      <p style="font-size:250%;"> <b>She ignites hearts with her emotionally charged</b> </p>
      <p style="font-size:250%;"> <b> music. Residing in her hometown, she grinds  </b> </p>
      <p style="font-size:250%;"> <b> towards her growing music career. Laurens music 
    <p style="font-size:250%;"><b>crafts lyrics exploring the changes of life. </b></p>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <img class="aboutimage" style="float: right;" src="images/vine.png">
      <img class="aboutimages123 " src="images/about img 2.jpg" style="float: left;">
      <p style="font-size:250%;"><b>Influenced by 90s-2000s alternative rock and 80s </b></p>
      <p style="font-size:250%;"><b>pop, Lauren's sound fuses alternative pop/rock </b></p>
      <p style="font-size:250%;"><b> indie pop. Guitar in hand since age 11 and a lifelong </b></p>
      <p style="font-size:250%;"><b>passion for singing, her artistic expression was </b></p>
      <p style="font-size:250%;"><b>fostered by her musically inclined family.</b> </style>
      </p>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <img class="aboutimage" style="float: left;" height="1px" src="images/vine.png">
      <img class="aboutimages123 " src="images/about img 3.jpg" style="float: right;">
      <p style="font-size:250%;"><b>Witnessing the passion in other artists' eyes at </b></p>
      <p style="font-size:250%;"><b>concerts fueled her own musical desires. </b></p>
      <p style="font-size:250%;"><b>Welcome to Lauren Phoebe's world, where  </b></p>
      <p style="font-size:250%;"><b>heartfelt melodies and lyrics merge to create  </b></p>
      <p style="font-size:250%;"><b>unforgettable journey of self-discovery. Follow </b></p>
      <p style="font-size:250%;"><b> her on an all major streaming platforms and </b></p>
      <p style="font-size:250%;"><b>experience the electrifying energy of music.</b></p>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p id="contact"> </p>
  <div class="contactcontainer">
    <div>
      <img style="margin-left: 156px; margin-top: 100px;" src="images/Lauren.png">
      <p style="margin-left: 80px;">Lauren Seel</p>
      <p style="margin-left: 80px;">Seellauren65@gmail.com</p>
    </div>
    <div class="social-media-container">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com" class="social-link" target="_blank">
        <img src="images/facebook-logo.png" alt="Facebook" class="social-logo">
      </a>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/laurenphebs" class="social-link" target="_blank">
        <img src="images/twitter-logo.png" alt="Twitter" class="social-logo">
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/laurenphoebemusic/" class="social-link" target="_blank">
        <img src="images/insta-logo.png" alt="Instagram" class="social-logo">
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@laurenphoebemusic?lang=en" class="social-link" target="_blank">
        <img src="images/tiktok-logo.png" alt="LinkedIn" class="social-logo">

      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- <p id="merch"> </p>
<p id="shows"> </p>  
<div class="merchcontainer">
  <p> coming soon </p>
</div> -->
</body>

</html>




Can you add a reproducible link and can add screenshot of what you are trying to achieve and whats its currently looking like?

thank you to everyone who viewed or commented, I actually was able to fix my own problem, thank you anyway
